# How to Display Cyrillic Characters properly from MySQL in PHP string variables?

Tags: php, mysql, string, character-encoding, cyrillic

I am using the following code to output results from my MySQL database table in a PHP foreach() loop. However, the characters stored in the database are Cyrillic and there are being displayed as question marks "??????" in the database table. $translated is the string variable that should display Cyrillic characters in the Ukrainian language but are just showing as question marks. Please let me know

```
<?php

/*** mysql hostname ***/
$hostname = 'localhost';

/*** mysql username ***/
$username = 'testname';

/*** mysql password ***/
$password = 'pass234';

try {

    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=testdatabase", $username, $password);

    /*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/
   /* echo 'Connected to database'; */
    }
  catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit();
    }

  ?>


  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>MLC Translate Tool</title>
     <!--IE Compatibility modes-->
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <!--Mobile first-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/logo1.ico"/>

      <!-- global styles-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/components.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css"/>
      <!--end of global styles-->
      <!--plugin styles-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/select2/css/select2.min.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/datatables/css/scroller.bootstrap.min.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/datatables/css/colReorder.bootstrap.min.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/datatables/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/pages/dataTables.bootstrap.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/plugincss/responsive.dataTables.min.css" />
      <!-- end of plugin styles -->
      <!--Page level styles-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/pages/tables.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="#" id="skin_change" />
      <!--End of page level styles-->

   </head>

  <body class="datatable_page">



     <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover " id="sample_6">
         <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Original</th>
                <th>Translated</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
           </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>



  <?php

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_trp_dictionary_en_us_uk;";

  foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
  {
    $original = $row['original'];
    $translated = $row['translated'];



     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>$original</td>";
     echo "<td>$translated</td>";
     echo "<td></td>";
     echo "<td></td>";
     echo "</tr>";
  }

  ?>
  </tbody>
  </table>


     <script src="js/components.js"></script>
     <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
     <!--end of global scripts-->
     <!--plugin scripts-->
     <script src="vendors/select2/js/select2.js"></script>
     <script src="vendors/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
     <script src="js/pluginjs/dataTables.tableTools.js"></script>
     <script src="vendors/datatables/js/dataTables.colReorder.js"></script>
     <script src="vendors/datatables/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script src="vendors/datatables/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
     <script src="js/pluginjs/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
     <script src="vendors/datatables/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
     <script src="vendors/datatables/js/dataTables.rowReorder.min.js"></script>
     <script src="vendors/datatables/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
     <script src="vendors/datatables/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
     <script src="vendors/datatables/js/buttons.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script src="vendors/datatables/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
     <script src="vendors/datatables/js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>
     <!-- end of plugin scripts -->
     <!--Page level scripts-->
     <script src="js/pages/datatable.js"></script>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: You might want to read up on [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: See "question mark" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored